# Add syntax highlighting language for diff

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I find that one of the best ways to demonstrate code examples, especially when picking apart something complicated or detailed, is to use diff hunks to illustrate differences.

This is something that still isn't done very often but I definitely see it more in blogs and articles more than in years past.

The reason that this works so well is that especially if the change being shown is a small part of a line, and even if the hunks are up to 6 lines or so in total, the color and the alignment draws the reader into the exact spots where code has changed. This is much better than pasting two larger chunks of code and putting the burden on the reader to pick apart the change.

The issue I am alluding to is that when I put in the `<!-- language: lang-diff -->` comment above a code block in SO, this is not recognized. I'm just looking for a very light implementation of the diff language, which is probably the world's simplest syntax highlighting routine ever. If a string starts with `+`, make the text of the rest of the line green, and if a line starts with `-`, make it red. Otherwise, do not color the line.

In the meantime I just use `<!-- language: lang-none -->` instead, the familiar diff format still helps because of the alignment and the repetition and the `+`s and `-`s. Coloring the lines would be really nice though.

As for those of you out there who never use diffs and can't stand them, well, this question doesn't really apply, and it won't take away any of the existing highlighting functionality that you know and love. In particular I am talking about adding a subtle color highlighting *when diff output is used as a code block in a question or an answer*. Not anything more custom or complicated than this.

Personally I find the usefulness of diffs to be self-evident. They draw the reader in to the exact thing that changed, it makes it so much easier to visualize the action that a piece of code has gone through. Yeah, if one has photographic memory, perhaps it's just moot... I have the opposite tendency, large walls of text put me to sleep, so anything that helps to pinpoint important information helps.

Comment: So... sacrifice coloring the code based on keywords just to make some lines green and red? It's a *syntax* highlighter, not a difference highlighter.

Comment: When I look at a diff (which is a special format that begins each line with either a space, a plus or a minus) I really do not want syntax highlighting. Every tool ever already does it this way. They also usually add the green and red. Anyway, this proposal does not take away from regular syntax highlighting at all... I'm just saying can we add a new language specification to support line based coloring.

Comment: Yes, but if you apply it to a code block, none of the code will be highlighted based on syntax. How many people even use diff formatting anyways? I've personally never seen a code block with pluses and minuses in front of lines in all my time on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeah this isn't a real common style yet, but it works really well for me. Tell me though, how many times have you seen a question asked which contains a 100 line code dump, and then an answer is posted with a 95 line code dump, presumably that has surgically fixed the glaring issues. You could not possibly tell me that if the answerer had posted an actual diff here in diff format that this would be any worse.

Comment: @animuson [unified diff for code block changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330020/), [Does multi-file unified diff requires Index: lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308241/), [Unified diff: What does @@ mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611634/), [Can't apply unified diff patch on Solaris](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477580/) - just have to know what to look for.  They're not incredibly common, and they don't stick just one one other tag so you tend to have to look to find more than one... but they're out there.

Comment: ... they also tend to be well asked questions, and thus receive fewer flags or close votes and thus even lower on the radar of people who would otherwise see them.  They get answered and disappear to all but the searchers rather than the browsers of popular or problematic questions.  Note that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1651996/289086) is what the OP is trying to avoid (the second large code block).

Comment: How would the system know which other code block to compare against?

Comment: @BoltClock it doesn't need to (diff already did that for you).  You could make it look something like http://i.stack.imgur.com/WrUIo.png - or an example for a similar request for Redmine: [diff code coloring using coderay](http://www.redmine.org/issues/5199) to see whats being asked.  When you have something that is a diff file, syntax highlight lines with '+' as green and '-' as red and '@' with another color.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @MichaelT, i am glad someone understands what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: @StevenLu the understanding of it depends on if you've seen it and used it.  I used to be a redmine admin where we had svn and a large application (and a bit branch phobic).  Sometimes for issues where we knew the code was going to change before the issue could be completely fixed, we'd attach diffs to the issue rather than fighting with long lived branches.  In early code review days (before we got svn integration working nicely) we'd attach diffs for code review to the issue. If you haven't used them, you wouldn't know what it *could* look like... and then there's patches from usenet days.

Comment: Well maybe I'm just weird because I didn't really start coding seriously and using version control till the mid 2000's so by this time there were plenty of GUI tools but even still, the only feasible way to actually visualize *what happened* is through diffs. How does a programmer not use diffs, repeatedly, day in and day out, is simply beyond me. What do people do? Keep code in their head? BAHAHAHA! Personally... i maintain (and use, like, every 10 minutes every day when I do any sort of work) my own branch of google diff-match-patch, a diff program that does a **character-wise diff**...

Comment: Note that while this isn't as common on Stack Overflow, it *does* find use on [other sites](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/133795/38168) that are more [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73771/46212) related than SO.

Comment: I could have used this here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195081/bash-regular-expression-comparison-fail-for-hex-byte-x01/383897#383897

Comment: I could have used this here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14681/1553

Comment: Any updated on this? Using code of the questioner with changes is very hard to see.

Comment: This would be useful on SO teams. An answer I'm writing involves looking at diffs and I'm sure my team members would appreciate having colored output to read through

Comment: @Kaz and @x-yuri used plain `patch` output. Good:you can copy it into a local diff viewer. Less handy way for a writer involves including a link to a github gist. Bad: when you want to doodle a diff by hand real-quick, it makes you obey formal diff syntax. For the latter `alias doodle-diff='(f1=$(mktemp); $EDITOR $f1; f2=$(mktemp); $EDITOR $f2; diff -u $f1 $f2)'` could help

Comment: Another thing I wanted to mention, friend of mine is a lawyer and they have some kind of plugin they use with MS Word for their work to generate diffs, because their legal documents and contracts need to be almost as precise as code needs to be, and lawyers using diff tools is a fairly substantial validation of my stance on working with diffs. it's a level of abstraction. Using diffs when working with changing data is just as powerful as leveraging calculus in the analysis of quantitative models.

Comment: Another comment is that in github markdown, you can just add `diff` after the three backticks that begin a code block, and it does it nicely.

Answer (score 22):

Since Stack Overflow has [migrated to highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) and there is a [diff highlighter (search for "diff" on the website)](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/) available for that tool, I wonder why it is still unsupported on SO. It should be easy to activate. So I am suggesting that somebody does that. Presently, neither of

- `diff`, `lang-diff`,
- `patch`, `lang-patch`

yield the desired result.

*(OT: The same is true for Groovy and other popular languages.)*

Comment: It was there, but it's been [turned off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408993/12695027). I expect the mentioned "US holiday" is the 4th of July.. + 6-8 units.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether this is apples and oranges or not. There's a HTML diff that shows the history of edits, but I'm talking about an actual syntax highlighting language in markdown code blocks.

Comment: That is what I am talking about too.

Comment: There are many formatting options supported by highlight.js but not on SO. If someone’s motivated, it’d be worth looking how (and even whether) SO actually uses highlight.js, and which version…

Comment: "Whether" is not the question. Did you follow my link to the corresponding announcement at all?

Comment: As a website for fixing code mistakes, this is absurd - even discord supports `diff` highlighting.

Answer (score 9):

I want diff-syntax highlighting too!

Stackoverflow uses uses [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), which currently doesn't have a `diff` syntax. If a diff syntax is added to Prettify, then it will probably be supported in Stackoverfow sooner or later.

To offer your support, you can:

1. Upvote and/or comment on these two issues:

   - https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/559
   - https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/62
2. Submit a PR with a file for diff syntax.

   In the "[For which languages does it work?](https://github.com/google/code-prettify#for-which-languages-does-it-work)" section it states:

   > If you'd like to add an extension for your favorite language, please look at `src/lang-lisp.js` and submit a pull request.

Comment: Since [Prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347738/google-code-prettify-has-been-officially-discontinued-its-time-for-se-to-maint) has been discontinued where does that leave us? 