# The revision history does not show the latest content correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, revision-history, diff

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60660705), I updated the name of the class from `Testing` to `SpellCheck`, but the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60660705/revisions), while looking it on inline mode, shows it as `TestingSpellCheck`.

> [image: "TestingSpellCheck" is shown on inline mode]

It's shown correctly when using the other modes, as side-by-side:

> [image: side-by-side renders it correctly]

Comment: reproed in inline mode. o_O

Comment: Yep. It looks like highlighting is completely broken/missing in *code blocks* for inline diffs.

Comment: _"It's shown correctly when using the other modes, as side-by-side"_, it doesn't highlight it though (except when you click on `Full`), so I wouldn't call that "correctly". The only mode that seems to work as expected is "Side-by-side Markdown".

Comment: The highlighting [flashes for a fraction of a second](https://i.imgur.com/5kmdFRb.gif) when the page is refreshed].

Comment: what's of interest is that the markup generated considers the merged name to be the actual class name: `<span class="hljs-title class_">TestingSpellCheck</span>`

Comment: What appears to be happening is that the difference highlighting is overwritten by the code syntax highlighting.

Comment: Also reported on MSE: [Sometimes diff isn't shown in edits to code inside source fences](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/366899/289905).

Comment: Another example: [**no highlight at all** when in "Side-by-side" mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J5BC.png) (my favorite mode)

Comment: More examples from a duplicate question of mine: [Diffs of code blocks are pretty consistently broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408840/diffs-of-code-blocks-are-pretty-consistently-broken). This makes reviewing Suggested Edits much harder; code changes are often invisible unless you use the Markdown view, which is in turn pretty bad for reviewing changes to big code blocks.

Comment: I'm investigating now  I can reproduce, this seems like a critical bug to fix

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A hotfix is now in place for this bug on both the `/posts/{id}/revisions` and `/review/suggested-edits/{id}` pages. Revisions will now be highlighted correctly in code blocks:

[image: A screenshot showing revision history properly highlighting removals and additions]

This is a problem with highlight.js overriding the classes used to show these additions and deletions. My hotfix disables highlight.js on the revisions page.

We have plans to revisit the syntax highlighting regression on the `/posts/{id}/revisions` and `/review/suggested-edits/{id}`, but for now our syntax highlighting is incompatible with also showing the highlighting for additions and deletions. Although the original bug has been fixed, I'm going to mark this specific bug as [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) until we fix the syntax highlighting regression introduced by the hotfix.

Comment: I'm just realizing that this is not just broken on the `/revisions` page but also on some review pages as highlighted in the comments above. Working on a hotfix for those pages too, thanks for your patience!

Comment: So.. we're going from not having diffs in code in one view to not know if the edit made the post better when adding a language tag? How are we suppose to know if the edit is good or not?

Comment: This makes me realize that [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408921/inline-formatting-no-longer-works-with-syntax-highlighting) is also caused by the same issue. Time to edit my (thankfully few) posts that used strikethrough in code blocks... Maybe there should be warnings for users if they do this from now on.

Comment: Along with the issues of overwriting diffs, I see [these types of warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HtVz.png) very often now. For most of those, I don't see any un-escaped HTML.

Comment: The hotfix is now also in place for the `/review/suggested-edits/{id}` page as well.

Comment: @Scratte your feedback has been noted - today's my first day working with the revisions page so I don't know what our intentions are here, but I'll follow up on the warning and code highlighting.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat could definitely be related to this change, I've flagged it to my team

Comment: [Example review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29335392). I can't review this because I cannot tell if it highlights correctly. Not even if I "Improve edit" or "Reject and edit". Before I could see the highlighting and then pick "Side-by-side Markup" to see if there were any code changes. Now I'm forced to pick "Side-by-side Markup" on every code post and Skip every edit that makes a change to the highlighting. If there's no change to the highlighting, I must open up the post on the side :(

Comment: @KylePollard: will the script be fixed for [inline formatting of code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408921/inline-formatting-no-longer-works-with-syntax-highlighting) as well? This was actually sometimes quite useful to let the reader focus on what changes were made.

Comment: Hey Kyle, is there any update on this?

Comment: People around the network are starting to believe [this is a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369541/786798) and not a hotfix applied - please, can something be done about it? I understand that the issue is likely not easy to fix, but this makes reviewing suggested edits a very frustrating experience - I used to review a lot in this queue, now I hardly do several a month...

Comment: @Luuklag this bug got incorrectly handed off between teams internally here and got forgotten - I've followed up on it and it will be prioritized in an upcoming sprint instead of being stuck in our backlog forever. Thank you for your reminder and patience!

Comment: @OlegValter Not to worry. If a US 4th of July holiday can go on until September, I think we don't have to feel inclined to review more than a post a year ;)

Comment: @KylePollard this bug seems to have come back: [sample review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32714400?_gl=1*fb14la*_ga*MTc5ODcyMjk2Ni4xNjYzMjE1Nzk2*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY2MzIxNTgwMC4xLjEuMTY2MzIxNzIxNi4wLjAuMA..)

Comment: This is fixed now: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423542/3023052

Answer (score 7):

This happens because of the "recent" highlight.js v11 migration (specifically [this feature removal](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/VERSION_11_UPGRADE.md#feature-removal)). highlight.js. The library now strips unescaped HTML inside `code` elements and that includes the `.diff-add`/`.diff-delete` `span`s SE uses in diffs to indicate addition/deletion.

Until a permanent fix is out, [I've created a userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/9154) that should resolve both issues (the original bug and the "hotfix"):

[image]