# Diffs of code blocks are pretty consistently broken

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits, diff

I'm not sure when this bug was introduced, because I've been mostly away from the site for a year and a half, but the "inline" and "side-by-side" views of code blocks seem to be very broken now.

Most noticeably, additions to code blocks (or additions *of* entire code blocks) don't show up in green in either view. Here are some examples of suggested edits with code insertions that you can only see highlighted in green from the "Side-by-side Markdown" view:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29279898
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29282664
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29278864

Worse than this, sometimes when a line is changed, the inline view shows both the old and new line, one after the other, with no red or green highlighting on either. See here for an example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29289465

This bug isn't specific to the Suggested Edits review queue, but it is of particular significance there, because it makes reviewing code changes more difficult. As far as I can tell given the bugs above, the only way you can quickly see if an edit made changes to any code blocks is to use the "Side-by-side Markdown" view. But that's not a viable way to do all your reviewing, either, because:

- like the side-by-side view, it has a tiny column width (so it's hard to read)
- it wraps the Markdown (so you can't distinguish a literal line break included in the markdown from render-time wrapping, and thus can't see if the edit author has garbled the whitespace)
- it doesn't let you select from just the left side or right side of the diff (so you can't copy the before code and the after code into a text editor and read them there)

Consequently, the only viable strategy for reviewing code changes in suggested edits seems to be to use the "Side-by-side Markdown" view to see which code blocks were changed, then paste the before and after versions of the rendered code from the "Side-by-side" view into an editor and review them there. This is kind of nuts, and I suspect that most reviewers are *not* this diligent and are consequently approving code changes they haven't even noticed are included in the edit.

Can we fix this?

For the sake of keeping this post comprehensible if the bug it refers to ever gets fixed, here are screenshots of each view of each of the four edits linked to above:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi6TY.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x7Xe.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IQ6h.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcfyc.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVucZ.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4LdW.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/17wPP.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG5tN.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWNoX.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FJKj.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3dbD.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJuVs.png

Comment: I *think* this is reporting the same bug as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408781/the-revision-history-does-not-show-the-latest-content-correctly), but it's possible you've noted additional brokenness not mentioned there.

Comment: @CodyGray I think you're right, and don't think I've found anything new. I'll close this as a dupe of that and add a comment there pointing out that there are some extra examples here.

Comment: Or just edit the examples into the original question.